# Why do I get these FS shutdown errors with a loopback installation of Ubuntu on NTFS?

Tags: linux, filesystems, io, shutdown, loop-device

#### Edit:

The "duplicate" does **not** answer this question. First, I can't even `mount --move /host /elsewhere` because I get an error saying that moving mounts under a shared point is not supported. Secondly, the problem comes up **even when `/host` is never mounted at all**. (This occurs if the directory `/host` does not exist, so that it simply *cannot* be mounted during boot.) So the problem is still unresolved.

---

I've installed Ubuntu in loopback mode on a file on an NTFS partition, booting via GRUB as follows:

```
set uuid="[SOME_UUID]"
set img="/path/to/root.disk"
loopback loop0 "$img"
set root=(loop0)
linux /vmlinuz rw root=UUID="$uuid" loop="$img"
initrd /initrd.img
```

This *works fine* until I shut down the system. Then I get the following errors (see image below):

```
[FAILED] Failed unmounting /host
[  OK  ] Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems
[  OK  ] Reached target Shutdown
[  ... ] loop: Write error at byte offset [offset], length [length]
[  ... ] Buffer I/O error on device loop0, logical block [LBA]
   ...
[  ... ] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block [LBA], lost async page write
   ...
[  ... ] Aborting journal on device loop0-0
[  ... ] JBD2 (?): Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for loop0-0
[  ... ] systemd-shutdown[1]: failed to finalize file systems, loop devices, ignoring
```

Note that `/host` is **not** in my `/etc/fstab`; it's auto-mounted by [lupin](https://launchpad.net/lupin).

I don't really understand why this should happen though.
Can someone explain what's going on and how to fix it so that I can loopback properly?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @roaima: It turns out this is not a duplicate; see edit.

Comment: That's fine. Now you've been able to add additional information to your question to demonstrate it's different I'm sure others will support me with the reopen nomination I've proposed.